# Learning Javascript, why do these two functions behave differently?

Tags: javascript

Learning Javascript and can't figure out why these two functions are different.  I saw this example (I added names to the functions):

```
var txt = ["a","b","c"];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {    
    setTimeout((function myBind(msg) { 
      return function myAlert() { alert(msg); } 
    })(txt[i]), 1000);        
}​
```

I see that a function that calls alert is being returned.  So I thought, why not just return it directly:

```
var txt = ["a","b","c"];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {    
    setTimeout( function() { alert(txt[i]);} ,1000);        
}​
```

This ends up alerting 'undefined.'  I understand that it's because it's trying to access txt[3] because after one second the loop has finished and i has been set to 3, but I don't understand how the original setup avoided this problem.

Comment: Research on closures and how that concept is used to control scope of a variable. Should kick you off in the correct direction.

Comment: Common problem; passing a function instead of passing a closure. Also used when passing functions for event handlers. Good reading on closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1**

The closures execute the script instantly and also allow you to pass a parameter inside
which is stored and remains stored inside that function. parameter==param

```
(function(param){})(parameter)
```

In your example the function returns another function which will be executed by setTimeout.

```
(function(param){
 return function(){
  alert(param)
 }
})(parameter)
```

And as you passed the parameter previously to the function it will return the right value.

**Example 2**

The setTimeout is called 3 times very fast but the parameter is not stored anywhere 
so it takes the last value know from  txt & i and as the loop is ended before the setTimeout is executed the value is 3

---

basically in the first example you store every txt[i] inside each function you create with those closures.

In the second one you don't store the txt[i]'s anywhere. you just tell the setTimout function to alert txt[i], which after 1second is the last one created by the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand how the msg can live til the end.  myAlert is being referenced by setTimeOut, but nothing is referencing myBind.  Shouldn't garbage collection pickup myBind...therefore also destroying myAlert?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up about closures. See this answer [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, `txt[i]` has been bound to a new variable, `msg`, which is a different location for each `function` being created.

In the second version, `i` is the same location for each of the `function`s because `i`'s scope is further up; there isn't a new `i` variable being created each time through the loop.

Comment: so there are 3 separate functions stored in memory?  So they look like this:  ' function(){ alert('a');}  function(){ alert('b')} function(){ alert('c');}'  Are those considered dynamic functions then?

Comment: @Alex There are 3 distinct function objects, right. The _body_ (code) of those function objects are the same, but with `msg` bound to a different object each time. As others have mentioned, these are closures (I guess you could think of closures of "dynamic functions" if it helps you understand them, initially).

Answer (score 0):

This is a concurrency problem.

setTimeout creates a "thread" for each execution, but won't evaluate the function until the timeout expires.

so, after a second, when the first timeout expires, your for loop has ended (with `i` having 3 as value), so accessing the `txt[i]` returns undefined.
Try printing the value of `i` inside the function with `console.log`